# C++ code in kernel CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

As I know, CUDA supports C and C++. But I can't' use C++ in my kernel.

I try a simple example like this

```
__global__ void simple(){
     cout<<"abc";
}
```

That is error. But if I change to `printf("abc");` it is right.

Can you explain for me? Thank you very much!

Comment: CUDA implements a *subset* of full C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From CUDA 7.5 nvidia slides:

**C++11 Supported features**:

- auto
- lambdas
- std::initializer_list
- variadic templates
- static_asserts
- constexpr
- rvalue references
- range based for loops

**C++ Not supported features**

- thread_local
- Standard libraries:  std::*

`std::cout` is defined in the C++ standard library which is not supported by CUDA. Use C `printf`

From CUDA 6.5, the ‘compute_11′, ‘compute_12′, ‘compute_13′, ‘sm_11′, ‘sm_12′, and ‘sm_13′ architectures are deprecated. So `nvcc` will compile by default to CC 2.0 enabling `printf` support.

More info [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support) and [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

CUDA doesn't link the libraries & header files that are required to use the `cout` function. However, you can enable the use of `printf()`

This answer explains the process which enables this feature:
[printing from cuda kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106615/printing-from-cuda-kernels)
quoted here for easier access:

> To enable use of plain printf() on devices of Compute Capability >= 2.0, it's important to compile for CC of at least CC 2.0 and disable the default, which includes a build for CC 1.0.
>
> Right-click the .cu file in your project, select Properties, select Configuration Properties | CUDA C/C++ | Device. Click on the Code Generation line, click the triangle, select Edit. In the Code Generation dialog box, uncheck Inherit from parent or project defaults, type compute_20,sm_20 in the top window, click OK.